# EntityDefinition does not support queryMore(), test records

Tags: apex, query

I have an error when query EntityDefinition: does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch. Query in for loop so I moved and it works. But i dont understand where does queryMore came from? Its not batch and I dont use it anywhere.  And is it possible to mock or insert EntityDefinition for test?

Also documentatio says that LIMIT is not supported, but it works https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_soql_limits.htm

```
    List<EntityDefinition> defs = [SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition]
    for (EntityDefinition def: defs) {            

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `queryMore` comes from the fact that Apex SOQL for loop automatically does query chunking to avoid heap issues. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm) for details. By removing the query from being inline within the for loop you avoid this effect.

As for mocking `EntityDefinition` metadata, this is possible using the JSON deserialization approach. This illustrates what I mean:

```
List<EntityDefinition> defs = [SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition LIMIT 1];

// This is the JSON string that you might want to hand-craft to provide
// your mock data, avoiding any hard-coded IDs, of course. Here I am simply
// showing that EntityDefinition supports JSON serialization and
// deserialization. It is by having a hand-crafted JSON of a serialized
// value that you can then provide a mock.
//
// Not all Salesforce API objects support JSON serialize/deserialize, but
// this one does
String asJson = JSON.serialize(defs[0]);

System.debug(asJson);

// This constructs an in-memory EntityDefinition based on your
// hand-crafted JSON mock data
EntityDefinition def = (EntityDefinition) JSON.deserialize(asJson, EntityDefinition.class);

System.debug(def);
```

As specific example, with a simple (cut-down) hand-crafted JSON might be:

```
String handCraftedExampleAsJson = '{"attributes":{"type":"EntityDefinition"},"QualifiedApiName":"Contract"}';

EntityDefinition handCraftedExample = (EntityDefinition) JSON.deserialize(handCraftedExampleAsJson, EntityDefinition.class);

System.debug(handCraftedExample);
```

This only contains the `QualifiedApiName` and nothing else. Add more detail as needed for your query (I have matched your question's query).

Comment: This is really useful example on how to mock sObjects in test classes the easy way. Thank you!

Comment: There is a fab library, the [SObjectFabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator), that uses this approach while allowing the JSON to be indirectly created via API calls.